# Is pthread_cond_broadcast() guaranteed to be atomic in regard to the rescheduling of the woken threads?

Tags: c++, linux, concurrency, pthreads

For an academic program I'm writing, it would be highly beneficial to have a set of threads enter the rescheduling process at the same time. So my question is, if there is a guarantee for [pthread_cond_broadcast(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_broadcast) to finish marking all threads as ready, before the first thread gets rescheduled?

Or to phrase it differently, may the calling thread leave the running state while more than 0, but not all of the affected Threads are competing for execution?

Edit: Since there was some confusion. I'm just asking if the expected result is guaranteed by some kind of standard I can't seem to find.

Comment: This really sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you trying to address?  How do you even **define** things like "at the same time" and "while" for processes and events that happen in nanoseconds?

Comment: How do you expect to actually observe these kinds of minute details of a particular platform? How do you determine if a particular thread is "ready", and what  does that mean to your academic program?

Comment: It is not the XY problem. I define "at the same time" as in: There doesn't exist a moment, where the processor chooses the next thread to schedule, where only a part of the affected threads are competing. Also on given Systems a yield may take several microseconds, which is not acceptable during the execution of this call.

Comment: *the processor*??  Now define **that**.  And also define "competing".  You need to look at things such as [execution pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipelining).  There is no singular "moment" in program execution.   *Also on given Systems a yield may take several microseconds, which is not acceptable during the execution of this call.*  So this **IS** an XY problem.  Why is it "not acceptable"?  What actual **problem** are you trying to solve/avoid?

Comment: The only thing execution pipelines and thread scheduling have in common is that scheduling uses instructions which can be pipelined. [Thread Scheduling](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169479&seqNum=3) in case you are interested. It's not the XY problem, since the goal literally is to have the threads compete for the running state [(Figure 4.4)](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/chap4_0131013769/elementLinks/04fig04.gif). Also I never stated it's a **problem** I'm trying to solve/avoid. I was asking if someone knows of a standard that guarantees the expected behavior.

Comment: This is the last reply you will get from me. In non sequential programs there exists a mechanism called thread scheduling to decide which instruction will be the next to give into your precious instruction pipeline. No matter how much parallel instructions you can compute, there has to be a basic ordering and synchronization, so the program will run in an controlled matter.